# POSIX write(2) to file descriptor in Swift fails with “Bad file descriptor”

Tags: swift, posix, file-descriptor

I am writing code in Swift to write to a file on a POSIX system (it is meant to work on Linux and OSX), and using the POSIX open(2) and write(2) system calls. However, I have found that, while writing to standard output works, doing so to an opened file descriptor gives a "Bad file descriptor" error; i.e., when writing to stdout:

```
> let bytes: [UInt8] = [ 65, 66, 67, 13, 10 ]
> write(STDOUT_FILENO, UnsafePointer(bytes), 5)
ABC
```

And when opening a file:

```
> let fd = open("/tmp/testfile", O_CREAT, 0o644)
fd: CInt = 3
> write(fd, UnsafePointer(bytes), 5) 
$R1: Int = -1
> print(String.fromCString(strerror(errno)))
Optional("Bad file descriptor")
```

This happens on both OSX (with import Darwin) and Linux (with import Glibc). In both cases, the file is created, and remains at size 0. Am I doing something wrong, or is there a bug in Swift or the Swift/C interface, and if the latter, does anyone know a workaround (that will work on Linux; using Cocoa/Foundation libraries is not yet an option)? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass the `O_WRONLY` ("open for writing only") or 
`O_RDWR` ("open for reading and writing") flag to `open()`,
otherwise you cannot write to the file descriptor:

```
let fd = open("/tmp/testfile", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0o644)
```